# Comparator won't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to make a "Zombies" map and you need five rotten flesh to open the door. I made hopper to put the items in the chest with a comparator to power the door. No matter how many items I put in the chest the comparator only sends a length of one to the redstone.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The output power is based on what percentage of the chest is full. The chest can hold `number of rows`*`number of columns`*`maximum stack size` pieces of rotten flesh, i.e. a lot. Are you only testing with 5 or have you tried filling the chest entirely?

Comment: I have filled the chest completely and it works but I want it to power the redstone at five

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a small (non-double) chest, try filling it like so:

[image: 64 in the first slot, 30 in the second slot, 1 in every other slot]

Then set up your redstone roughly like this:

[image: Comparator, two blocks of redstone, repeater, redstone leading to an iron door]

The comparator will output a signal with strength 1 if there are between 1 and 123 pieces of flesh in the chest, and strength 2 (or higher) if there are more. Putting 115 pieces of flesh in the chest means that five more pieces are needed to increase the strength. Once those five pieces are inserted, the repeater will activate, and power the door.

Comment: To make it a little nicer, you can have a Dropper feed the chest. This way, players won't see the chest's contents itself -- it'll look a lot cleaner!

Comment: @Schism I assumed that the chest was hidden away and that the hopper was the only thing visible to the player.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail A dropper or even a second hopper are easier to fill up due to less space. Also, a hopper simplifies the calculation of how many items you need because 15 divides nicely into 5.